# Application Insights has started throwing "Method Not Found" error

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I have started getting an error in ApplicationInsights on 8/26/2022 @3am EDT.  Our code hasn't change and has been running for a month without issue.  This error has started out of nowhere.

```
AI (Internal): [Redfield-Microsoft-ApplicationInsights-Extensibility-Web] TelemetryInitializer Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.SyntheticUserAgentTelemetryInitializer failed to initialize telemetry item System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.ActivityExtensions.Extract(System.Diagnostics.Activity, System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection)'.
    at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.Implementation.RequestTrackingExtensions.CreateRequestTelemetryPrivate(HttpContext platformContext)
    at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.Implementation.RequestTrackingExtensions.ReadOrCreateRequestTelemetryPrivate(HttpContext platformContext)
    at Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.Implementation.WebTelemetryInitializerBase.Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
```

When I try to search for help on this, I cannot find anything because Application Insights is used to help people find errors and exceptions... so when I try to get help, it provides help on how to use Application Insights data instead of providing information on what to do when Application Insights is reporting it's own error.

I am at a loss here, I don't know how to progress further to understand why this issue just started happening and what I can do to resolve it.  It would appear as if this issue is causing our Azure CPU usage to fly out of control and is causing the entire site to lag.

Application is written in VB.NET using v4.6.2.

To circumvent the issue, we have turned off Application Insights.  I was 1 version back, so it's possible there was an issue that was corrected and this will go away when the new version goes live (with the updated reference).

Comment: what is the framework you are using?Could you please share the source code ?

Comment: .NET v4.6.2.  I have updated the description.